# How to check listindex of combo in vb6?

Tags: oracle, vb6

I load values of combo boxes here but I don't want to set `ListIndex` property to -1.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    OPENCON
    RES.Open "DIVISION", CON, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
    If RES.RecordCount > 0 Then
        RES.MoveFirst
        For i = 0 To RES.RecordCount - 1
            CmbDiv.AddItem RES.Fields("DIV").Value
            CmbDiv.ItemData(CmbDiv.NewIndex) = RES.Fields("DIVID").Value
            RES.MoveNext
        Next
    End If
    RES.Open "HNM", CON, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
    If RES.RecordCount > 0 Then
        RES.MoveFirst
        For i = 0 To RES.RecordCount - 1
            CmbHouse.AddItem Trim(RES.Fields("HOUSE").Value)
            CmbHouse.ItemData(CmbHouse.NewIndex) = RES.Fields("HID").Value
            RES.MoveNext
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the code I used to modify record.

```
Private Sub CmdSave_Click()
    sql = "UPDATE STUDENT_RECORD_DATABASE SET "
    sql = sql + "ROLLNO= " & Val(CmbRNO) & ","
    sql = sql + "DIVID='" & Val(CmbDiv.ItemData(CmbDiv.ListIndex)) & "',"
    sql = sql + "HID=" & Val(CmbHouse.ItemData(CmbHouse.ListIndex)) & " "
    sql = sql + "WHERE ROLLNO= " & Val(CmbRNO) & ""
    Set RES = CON.Execute(sql)
End Sub
```

While running the code if I modify both division and house then it's ok
but when I let any one value of them(doesn't modify value) it shows error on the 3rd and 4th lines of `CmdSave_Click`:

> Invalid Property array value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after loading your data into the combobox, set the listindex to 0

```
Combo1.ListIndex = 0
```

it would be better though to check if listindex is -1, and if it is -1, then don't do the action, or give the user a warning that he should select something from the combobox